# Does python support character type?

Tags: python

When I am checking with data types I wonder why a char value is returning as string type.

Please see my input and output.

**Input:**

```
a = 'c'

type(a)
```

**Output:**

```
class 'str'
```

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: chr(n) will return a string with one character on it.

Comment: The more that I learn about character encoding, the more that I appreciate the choice not to have a character type in Python.  There are a lot of characters (although the only ones I can think of off the top of my head are national flag emoji) which cannot be represented in a single Unicode code point, so why not just be realistic and accept that line character literals are fundamentally strings?

Answer (score 44):

No.

Python does not have a character or `char` type. All single characters are strings with length one.

Comment: @Avinash No problem. If it helped you can mark this as answered. Or any of the other ones that answer the question.

Answer (score 8):

There is no [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) type for character in Python, there are `int`, `str` and `bytes`. If you intend to user character, you just can go with `str` of length 1.

Note that Python is dynamically typed, you do not need to declare type of your variables.

All string you create using quote `'`, double quote `"` and triple quote `"""` are string ([unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)):

```
type("x")
str
```

When invoking [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) function `type`, it returns a `type` object representing the type of your variable:

```
type(type("x"))
type
```

Integer and character do have mapping function (encoding), natively the sober map is ASCII, see `chr` and `ord` builti-in functions.

```
type(123)
int

type(chr(65))
str

type(ord("x"))
int
```

If you must handle special characters that are not available in default charset, you will have to consider encoding:

```
x = "é".encode()
b'\xc3\xa9'
```

The function encode, convert your sting into bytes and can be decoded back:

```
x.decode()
'é'
```

Method `encode` and `decode` belongs respectively to object `str` and  `bytes`.

Comment: This is a very detailed (but not necessarily complete) statement about characters in Python but it is too complex for such a simple and straightforward question.

Comment: @jonspencer, thank you for sharing your opinion. Is it really such a simple question?

Comment: @ jlandercy I do agree with you that there is perhaps underlying complexity depending upon encoding, but I do think that the question was very simple and straightforward - is there a character type, and why did `type` return `str`? @collector answered simply, which I think reflected the level of expertise of the asker.  You provided a more detailed response more appropriate for a different asker.  Had you stopped at your first line your answer would have been upvoted.

Comment: @Jon Spenser I think it's worthwhile to have both a shorter answer and a "why" answer.  StackOverflow is more of a wiki with a question and answer format than it is a question and answer site, so laser-focus on the asker isn't necessary as it would be if you were asked a question personally.

Comment: Python is *not* weakly typed. Dynamic, yes, but weak, no. Weak typing would mean, for example, that something like `1 + "2" == 3`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bytes type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) which may be analogous depending on why you are asking.

```
>>> b'a'
=> b'a'
```

---

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit